# PHP autologout inactive users

Tags: php, debugging

first time poster here, finally decided to make an account here after i used too many hours of my workday trying to solve this problem yesterday.

so i have this "sessionCheck.php" script that is supposed to logout the user if he is inactive see code below. Right now the variable $inactive = 15; which should mean that if the user is inactive for 15 seconds, they should be logged out and redirected to the logout page. However for some weird reason, this always takes 120seconds, no matter if i set $inactive to 15 seconds, 1 second or 60 seconds, it always takes 120 seconds. but if i set the variable to lets say 130, it doesn't logout and redirect at all anymore, only refreshes the page.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, as it doesn't really seem logical.

```
<?
session_start();

// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 15;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
        { session_destroy(); header("Location: login.php?loggut");
        $db->Execute("UPDATE tblTimeLog SET LogoutTime = NOW() WHERE sid ='".session_id()."'".$row['konsulentid'].'');

        }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time(); ?>
```

My first thought was that it must be some other script that overrides or automatically logs the user out already someone interfering with this script, but if i run the test site without this script it doesn't logout at all either.

Again, first time poster, so sorry if break any guidelines, i'm fairly certain that i didn't tho! all help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this will fix your issue, but it may be a part of it. 
Is `Location: login.php?loggut` correct? Should it be ?logout    ?

Comment: ah yeah it is correct, the previous programmer that was working on this used a weird mix of norwegian and english naming. hence the "loggut"!

Comment: Hi @BalderKjøs, I executed your code with some minor changes suggested by Frankey and it works perfect. I think just rename your variables names give some other name, because somewhere $inactive possible used to rename it and then check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vijay ! atleast this confirms that it indeed SHOULD be working, i will try your suggestions and see if i can make it work :) thank you

Comment: @vijay hey again! im still trying here! would you care to show your code that worked for you? i still can't get it to work, i changed variable names and a few other small changes, but still no luck.

Comment: Yeah you can check my code by this link  https://eval.in/708183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to put the header redirect after the query and exit the script so you can be sure the query is processed and the `$_SESSION['timeout']` is not updated after you try to logout the user.

You are also destroying the session before you use the actual session_id() in your query once more.

Give this a try:

```
<?
session_start();

// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 15;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
        { 
               $db->Execute("UPDATE tblTimeLog SET LogoutTime = NOW() WHERE sid ='".session_id()."'".$row['konsulentid'].'');
               session_destroy(); 
               header("Location: login.php?loggut");
               exit(); 
        }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time(); 
?>
```

Comment: I Tried with these changes and still getting the same issue, it was still a good point to make these changes anyways although it didn't solve my problem!

Comment: hey again! im still at this, so yeah, this works as in if the user makes an action after 15 seconds, the page will instead log them out and direct them to to "login.php?loggut". However, the page does not refresh automatically after the 15 seconds! i tried using header("refresh: 0;Location: login.php?loggut") but then it still doesn't refresh by itself, and if refreshed manually it doesnt understand the location anymore.

Comment: isn't that what you want? As long as the user is active within ever 15 seconds, he will stay logged in. After 15 seconds of inactivity he will be logged out. That is what is happening now, right? 
15 seconds is pretty short for a max duration of inactivity for a user. If you make the inactivity time  like an hour, the user probably do some page visits where the timeout session will be updated every page visit.

Comment: ofcourse, the 15 seconds is just for testing purpose, our users will be logged out after 40minutes inactivity, however i want the site to refresh automatically, but i finally figured out why it wouldn't work for more than 120seconds. For anyone interested it was because the previous coder that worked on this site decided to put a 120second refresh in every single header through the entire site. so i just need to remove that and it should be fine! thanks for all the help!